# Change linux user default ownership on file creation?

Tags: linux, deployment, permissions, file-ownership

Seems like something which should be easy to find but Googling brings up lots of unrelated tasks.

I have a deploy scipt which runs under the user "deploy" but my web server runs as "nginx" I want the web server to be able to write to the deployed files.

Ive added nginx to the deploy user group and I believe I can write files with deploy user with the ownership "nginx:deploy" easily now but by default it creates files as "deploy:deploy" obviously which nginx won't write too.

Is there anyway to change the user so that by default creates files as "nginx:deploy" to solve this problem?

Comment: If owner group is enough, you can set the setguid bit for the group on the folder you create the files in. YOu could get files to have `deploy:nginx` ownership with that. Not sure if you can work with that though.

Comment: Off-topic. Belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix/Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `install` command has options to control the owner and group of the files it creates. But in general, only `root` can create files as a different user. Maybe you can configure `sudoers` to let the `deploy` user run the commands it needs with `sudo` as the `nginx` user.